# Is ';;' a chaining operator in Unix? How does it work?

Tags: command-line

My teacher lists the following chaining operators:

```
& && ( ) ; ;; | || new line
```

How is ;; a chaining operator and what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your teacher will probably talk later on about `case` statements in `bash` and how each option statement is closed by `;;`.

As in:

```
case $space in
[1-6]*)
  Message="All is quiet."
  ;;
[7-8]*)
  Message="Start thinking about cleaning out some stuff.  There's a partition that is $space % full."
  ;;
9[1-8])
  Message="Better hurry with that new disk...  One partition is $space % full."
  ;;
99)
  Message="I'm drowning here!  There's a partition at $space %!"
  ;;
*)
  Message="I seem to be running with an nonexistent amount of disk space..."
  ;;
esac
```

See [TLDP Bash Guide for Beginners - 7.3. Using case statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)